# Resize MSChart to Fit Pagesize Before Printing

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, charts

I am struggling to figure out how to get an MSChart to fill the entire page when printing.  Can someone tell me why the code below does not work and/or suggest another approach.  I apologize for my ignorance but, all of the printing I have done so far has been done through Crystal and other reporting frameworks so I generally never have to work directly with the PrintDialog and PrintPreviewDialog.  Thanks in advance.

```
// Printing Code
Size pageSize = new Size(this.Chart.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width, this.Chart.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height);
this.Chart.Size = pageSize;

// This properly previews my chart but, it does not fill up the page                    
this.Chart.Printing.PrintPreview();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I finally figured out how to accomplish what I was trying to do.  It boiled down to me not understanding how to use a PrintDocument with the Graphics object.  The code that I used to accomplish the task is below.  I really hope this helps someone.  Also, I highly recommend the MSFT Chart Sample Code.  It has proven to be invaluable to me as I create these charts.  The link is: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418

```
    public void PrintPreviewIncompleteJobsByStatus()
    {
        // Set new print document with custom page printing event handler
        chart.Printing.PrintDocument = new PrintDocument();
        chart.Printing.PrintDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ChartGenericFormat_PrintPage);

        chart.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

        // Print preview chart
        chart.Printing.PrintPreview();
    }

    private void ChartGenericFormat_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        // Calculate first chart position rectangle
        Rectangle chartPosition = new Rectangle(ev.MarginBounds.X, ev.MarginBounds.Y, ev.MarginBounds.Width, ev.MarginBounds.Height);

        // Draw chart on the printer graphics
        chart.Printing.PrintPaint(ev.Graphics, chartPosition);

    }
```