# How to resize a chart before printing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, charts, printing, resize

I would like to print a chart in my vb.net application but when I print it, it's very small and I can't find how to resize it.

For now, I'm using this code: (Found here : [Some msdn printing subject](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/c5d88ab3-031a-485f-972f-936076ed8f2e/full-page-chart-printing-in-landscape-with-printer-selection?forum=vbgeneral))

```
Private Sub BT_Print_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BT_Print.Click
    Dim pdS As New PrintDocument()

    AddHandler pdS.PrintPage, AddressOf pds_PrintPage
    pdS.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True

    Dim PrintDialog1 As New PrintPreviewDialog
    PrintDialog1.Document = pdS

    If (PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK) Then
        Chart_Requis.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        pdS.Print()
End If

End Sub

Private Sub pds_PrintPage(sender As Object, ev As PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim chartPosition As New Rectangle(1, 1, ev.MarginBounds.Width, ev.MarginBounds.Height)

    Chart_Requis.Printing.PrintPaint(ev.Graphics, chartPosition)
End Sub
```

After all my attempt I just reached to move margins... which is good but I still cannot read my chart correctly...

Do someone had the same issue and found a solution ?

[image: This is how it appears on the preview]

----------------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------------

As I explain it the comment of your answer, I now can change chart's position and size but blank squares appears  and I don't know why !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found something which worked for me here and I adapt it to my case : [Another Stackoverflow subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997520/resize-mschart-to-fit-pagesize-before-printing)

I let you see the final chart here :
[image: Final Chart]

I add a dialogbox to choose the printer and adapt a bit the original code as you can see here :

```
Private Sub BT_Print_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BT_Print.Click

    Print_Preview()
End Sub

Public Sub Print_Preview()
    Dim Print_Doc As PrintDocument
    Print_Doc = Chart_Requis.Printing.PrintDocument


    AddHandler Print_Doc.PrintPage, New PrintPageEventHandler(AddressOf Print_Page)

    'SHEET PARAMETERS
    Print_Doc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    Print_Doc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(0, 1, 1, 1)
    Print_Doc.DefaultPageSettings.Color = True

    'CHOOSING PRINTER AND OTHER PARAMETERS
    Dim Print_dlg As New PrintDialog
    Print_dlg.Document = Print_Doc
    Dim result As DialogResult = Print_dlg.ShowDialog()

    'IF DIALOGBOX OK THEN CONTINUE OTHERWISE NO
    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then

        'PUT MARKERS TO THE RIGHT SIZE
        For i = 0 To Chart_Requis.Series.Count - 1
            Chart_Requis.Series(i).MarkerSize = 1
        Next

        'CHECKING BEFORE PRINTING
        Chart_Requis.Printing.PrintPreview()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Print_Page(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ev As PrintPageEventArgs)
    'DEFINI LA POSITION ET LA TAILLE DU GRAPHIQUE
    Dim chartPosition As New Rectangle(-70, -50, 2500, 2300)
    Chart_Requis.Printing.PrintPaint(ev.Graphics, chartPosition)
End Sub
```

Hope it will help someone in the same trouble than me today...

Comment: Hi Macros, it’s august and I got my childrens in the sea time to time, so about that sorry for not response. I’m glad you have found the solution for your issue(I hope It’s  temporary as I doesn’t like your solution even my solution, there needs more time to think about). Stay safe ;) Gent

Comment: Hi @G3nt_M3caj , no problem and thanks again for the time you gave for my subject ;) Yes, it's far to be perfect, but I'm really not a specialist at all ^^. So, for now it do the job, and it's already a good thing for me ! Wish you well too !

Answer (score 1):

By image you have posted seems your issue is ChartArea not Chart Control.
You need to increase Area of your Chart Area.
In the example below (which can help you in that) I have used two parameters scaleX and scaleY .
You can work on those two to find the right size becomes on print.
Note that.: As Chart Area in the example I’ve used the first of your Chart Control, but, you can use another calling it by name. Hope is what you needs.

```
Private Sub BT_Print_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BT_Print.Click


    Using pdS As New PrintDocument()

        Dim scaleX As Single = 1.5
        Dim scaleY As Single = 1.2

        With pdS.DefaultPageSettings
            .Landscape = True
            .Margins = New Margins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        End With

        Chart_Requis.Printing.PrintDocument = pdS

        AddHandler pdS.PrintPage, Sub(obj As Object, ev As PrintPageEventArgs)
                                      Using ev.Graphics
                                          With Chart_Requis.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault

                                              Dim initialP As DataVisualization.Charting.ElementPosition = .Position

                                              Dim newP As Rectangle = New Rectangle With {
                                              .X = CInt(initialP.X),
                                              .Y = CInt(initialP.Y),
                                              .Width = CInt(initialP.Width * scaleX),
                                              .Height = CInt(initialP.Height * scaleY)
                                              }

                                              .Position.FromRectangleF(newP)

                                              Chart_Requis.Printing.PrintPaint(ev.Graphics, ev.MarginBounds)

                                              .Position = initialP

                                          End With
                                      End Using
                                  End Sub

        Using PrintDialog1 As New PrintPreviewDialog With {
            .Document = pdS
        }

            If (PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK) Then
                pdS.Print()
            End If
        End Using

    End Using


End Sub
```

Comment: First thank you so much @G3nt_M3caj for your answer, I can now change the chart size and position but some blank sqares appear I don't understand why ! I will edit my post to show you because I don't know how to do it here...

Comment: Try to comment this part : “.Position.FromRectangleF(newP)”. It may doesn’t need only the Area resize as it’s resized by itself (all Chart Control). If it works you will comment other parts related to ".Position". Have a nice day :)

Comment: I tried, blank squares disapear but it do not resize anymore... I tried a lot of thing between including avoid to use rectangleF by setting position manually but blank squares are still here, I don't understand from where they can from !
Still thank you and have a nice day too ! ;)