# Saving image from a chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, savefiledialog, save-image

I need to program a button to save a graph, generated with my software, as an image. I looked around and I've found `Chart.SaveImage` command, so I programmed the abovementioned button as follows:

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    SaveFileDialog2.Filter = "PNG Image (*.png*)|*.png|JPEG Image (*.jpg*)|*.jpg|Bitmap Image (*.bmp*)|*.bmp|TIFF Image (*.tiff*)|*.tiff"
    Select Case Path.GetExtension(SaveFileDialog2.FileName)
        Case ".png"
            Chart1.SaveImage(SaveFileDialog2.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Png)
        Case ".jpg"
            Chart1.SaveImage(SaveFileDialog2.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Case ".bmp"
            Chart1.SaveImage(SaveFileDialog2.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Bmp)
        Case ".tiff"
            Chart1.SaveImage(SaveFileDialog2.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Tiff)
    End Select
End Sub
```

While debugging, when I press the button, it seems that it hasn't been programmed because at the pressure nothing seems to happen. What I need, as you can understand from my code, is that a SaveFile Dialog appears and I can choose where to save the image and its name and format. Thanks for any answers or comments. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as follows:

You forgot to call `SaveFileDialog2.ShowDialog`. So without showing `SaveFileDialog` window that allows you to chose a path nothing happens.

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    SaveFileDialog2.Filter = "PNG Image (*.png*)|*.png|JPEG Image (*.jpg*)|*.jpg|Bitmap Image (*.bmp*)|*.bmp|TIFF Image (*.tiff*)|*.tiff"
    If SaveFileDialog2.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Select Case Path.GetExtension(SaveFileDialog2.FileName)
            Case ".png"
                Chart1.SaveImage(SaveFileDialog2.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Png)
            Case ".jpg"
                Chart1.SaveImage(SaveFileDialog2.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Case ".bmp"
                Chart1.SaveImage(SaveFileDialog2.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Bmp)
            Case ".tiff"
                Chart1.SaveImage(SaveFileDialog2.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Tiff)
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it works properly. Is there a way to increase image resolution when saving it?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487365/how-to-resize-a-chart-before-printing-in-vb-net/63494332#63494332. The concept is the same